# Adding items to Android Maps Overlay does not immediately show on map. How do I fix?

Tags: android, android-maps

I can't figure out how to tell my Map to redraw its overlays once I've updated them.
Can someone enlighten me?

Currently the user has to touch the screen before the map is redrawn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must call [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) from an UI thread or [postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29) from an non-UI thread on the MapView object you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have been facing the same issue.But it was just because of some misconception about Location Listener. In my case I registered the a separate Broadcast Receiver which in turn calls a MapActivity that possess my LocationListener. Although LocationListener itself is a Broadcast Receiver which does not need any of the External Broadcast Receiver to be called. After removing the extra Broadcast receiver and directly implementing Location Listener I fixed my bug.

Comment: Cool, I'll revisit my app and see if that helps. Thanks Prerna.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `populate()` on the overlay that contains the pins.

Comment: After I've added it to the map overlays?

Comment: Yep, any time you add a pin to it, I believe you need to call `populate()`